# Kibana public IP site cannot be reached

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, gcloud, google-compute-engine

Cannot get Kibana's public IP to work from google compute engine. Says the site cannot be reached, though Elasticsearch works through public IP if I change the `elasticsearch.yml` from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`

Turned off nginx to test just Kibana.

Running on: Ubuntu 16.04, Elasticsearch 5.6.0, Kibana 5.6.0

Firewall was allowed for `port 5601` [Kibana firewall screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEczB.png)

The `kibana.yml` file has the following:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
```

Running the `netstat -natp | grep 5601`, I get:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5601            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

And running `sudo netstat -tupln` returns:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1916/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5601            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10615/node          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1447/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      8490/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1916/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1447/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      8490/java           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1447/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1156/dhclient       
udp        0      0 10.128.0.100:123        0.0.0.0:*                           1702/ntpd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           1702/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1702/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           1447/systemd-resolv 
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fe80:123 :::*                                1702/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                1702/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                1702/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                1447/systemd-resolv
```

`curl -i localhost:5601` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
kbn-name: kibana
kbn-version: 5.6.0
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 217
accept-ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 23:27:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
<script>var hashRoute = '/app/kibana';
var defaultRoute = '/app/kibana';
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length) {
  window.location = hashRoute + hash;
} else {
  window.location = defaultRoute;
```

`sudo systemctl status kibana` indicates that kibana service is active and running

It seems like the port 5601 doesn't work on any instances in Google Compute Engine, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting Kibana's public IP in the `server.host` setting in kibana.yml?

Comment: Tried that but still a no go

Answer (score 0):

Making a new separate firewall rule for port 5601 solved the issue! Thanks for the input everyone

Comment: Came in the next day and it stopped working again, recreating the port 5601 did not work...